# Make particles disappear after they have reached a certain position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

I am trying to create a bleeding effect in my game and I would like to make particles disappear not after an amount of time, but rather after they have reached a position lower than the owner of the particle emitter.

I tried to attach a script that tries to do this but I can't seem to make the particles disappear.

```
public class Blood : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private ParticleSystem ps;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform owner;


    void Update()
    {
        ParticleSystem.Particle[] particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[ps.particleCount];

        int num = ps.GetParticles(particles);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            if (particles[i].position.y < owner.position.y)
            {
                particles[i].remainingLifetime = 0f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is `if (particles[i].position.y < owner.position.y)` being called at-all? You can use `Debug.Log` to verify.

Comment: I put a Debug.log after the if statement and they log registers, I think the problem is in how I access the individual particles. after the if statement

Comment: Are you assigning your ParticleSystem component to `ps` via the editor? If not you will want to grab that in your `Awake` method via `GetComponent<ParticleSystem>`. Also, you don't want to create a new `Particle[]` every frame like you are doing there. See: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.GetParticles.html

Comment: You're already accessing each individual with `particles[i].remainingLifetime`.  The log should be done in the `if` statement not after it. So, do you see log? also, is this the compete code you're using?

Comment: @MalcolmSmith `[SerializeField]` is used so the variables becomes visible in the Editor and OP can assign the objects from the Editor instead of code. I think that's the case here

Comment: I've solved it, problem was that by changing velocity I was not being able to see the change in direction, but I will change it so that it doesn't create a new particlesystem Array every frame. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but ParticleSystem.Particle is a value type (struct), so you are only manipulating a local copy. Call

```
ps.SetParticles(particles)
```

in the end to copy them back to the particle system.